# Why does sorted()'s key parameter require a keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, keyword-argument

If you inspect the signature of Python's built-in `sorted()` function like this:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.signature(sorted))
```

The signature is: `(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)`.

Based on my understanding of positional and optional arguments acquired [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments), it would seem like you could provide an `iterable` argument and then a `key` argument without needing a keyword `key=` for the `key` argument.  But you always need to specify `key=` when passing a `key` argument.  Why is that?

I understand that if you wanted to specify `reverse=True`, but without any `key` argument, you'd need a keyword for that, but I don't understand why you'd need to specify `key=` when you're providing a `key`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Python issue 26729](https://bugs.python.org/issue26729), an error in `sorted.__text_signature__`, which is missing the `/` and `*` required to indicate that `iterable` is positional-only and `key` and `reverse` are keyword-only. The patch is in patch review, assigned to Raymond Hettinger. Once the patched version is released, the signature should display as

```
(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

Comment: Actually, now I'm more confused.  Why not have the function work the way the current signature says?  What's the point of making the function work with keyword-only arguments?

Comment: @user123123123: `sorted` and `list.sort` used to take a `cmp` argument. When that was removed, making `key` and `reverse` keyword-only helped the transition by giving clearer errors for code still trying to use `cmp`. Also, it makes future changes to the interface easier, and you don't have to remember what order the arguments come in.